# In install4j, can you include both 32 and 64 bit version of an application in one install package and let the user decide which to install?

Tags: wix, 32bit-64bit, install4j

In install4j, can you include both 32 and 64 bit versions of an application in one install package and let the user decide which to install if the OS is 64-bit? Would the easiest/best solution be to create three projects? i.e. one parent/two children? I'm hesitant to do this because the majority of the included files are not architecture-specific and I'd like to keep everything in one project.

I'm also not tied to install4j if another installer can accomplish this, especially WiX, which is used by other groups in our company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently install4j cannot create a single media file for 32-bit and 64-bit. Since the 32-bit media file works on 64-bit Windows as well, this is usually not a big problem. Common 32-bit/64-bit media files may be implemented for install4j 6.

In any case, you do not need separate projects for 32-bit and 64-bit installers. You just add two media files in the "Media" step of the install4j IDE, one for the 32-bit installer and another one for the 64-bit installer, with different settings on the "32-bit or 64-bit" step of the media wizard.

As for platform specific files, just add two file sets and exclude them as appropriate in the "Customize project defaults->Exclude files" step of the media wizard.